# Assert.AreEqual() falha quando parece estar tudo certo

Tags: c#, .net, testes-de-unidade

Eu não consigo achar nenhum erro no meu algoritmo de Bubble Sort. Mas o *assert* retorna erro.

Estou passando argumentos errados para o `Assert.AreEqual()`?

```
//The method for testing
public static int[] BubbleSort(int[] vect)
    {
        for (int i = vect.Length-1; i >=1 ; i--)
        {
            for (int j = 0;  j < i;  j++)
            {
                if (vect[i]<vect[j])
                {
                    var aux = vect[i];
                    vect[i] = vect[j];
                    vect[j] = aux;
                }
            }
        }
        return vect;
    }


    [TestMethod]
    public void TestBubbleSort()
    {
        int[] vetor = new int[10];
        vetor[0] = 9;
        vetor[1] = 8;
        vetor[2] = 7;
        vetor[3] = 5;
        vetor[4] = 6;
        vetor[5] = 2;
        vetor[6] = 3;
        vetor[7] = 1;
        vetor[8] = 4;
        vetor[9] = 0;

        int[] sortVector = new int[10];
        sortVector[0] = 0;
        sortVector[1] = 1;
        sortVector[2] = 2;
        sortVector[3] = 3;
        sortVector[4] = 4;
        sortVector[5] = 5;
        sortVector[6] = 6;
        sortVector[7] = 7;
        sortVector[8] = 8;
        sortVector[9] = 9;

        Assert.AreSame(sortVector, Study.BubbleSort(vetor), "Error");
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não vou avaliar o algoritmo, mas sim o teste de unidade. Ele está errado. O método [`Assert.AreSame()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert.aresame?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=mstest-net-1.3.2#Microsoft_VisualStudio_TestTools_UnitTesting_Assert_AreSame_System_Object_System_Object_) verifica se as duas variáveis apontam para o mesmo objeto. E obviamente elas não apontam. Você não está comparando as coisas que imagina. E note que não está usando o método indicado na pergunta.

Para resolver isso teria que usar métodos que analisam os valores de todos os elementos dos *arrays* e verificar se todos batem. Apenas se todos baterem é que está ok. Você pode usar [`Enumerable.SequenceEqual()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_SequenceEqual__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__) para fazer essa verificação, dentro de um [`Assert.IsTrue()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert.istrue?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=mstest-net-1.3.2#Microsoft_VisualStudio_TestTools_UnitTesting_Assert_IsTrue_System_Boolean_System_String_).

Comment: Obrigado, resolveu o problema e entendi como funciona o Assert.AreSame, antes eu havia utilizado o Assert.AreEqual() e também não tinha resolvido. Obrigado pela ajuda e me desculpem pelo inglês.